# Gson - parse a field with a string value containing \r\n

Tags: android, json, gson

I'll make this brief. I'm trying to parse some json with a field similar to this:

```
"some_string": "This is a string.\r\nIt also has returns and newlines"
```

Currently, GSON is parsing this only as "It also has returns and newlines" but I need the entire string value with \r\n intact.

Here's what I've got thus far:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json);
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
ParsedResponse response = new Gson().fromJson(reader, ParsedResponse.class);
```

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you need \r\n, then in you need append 3 **\\\** to escape characters (\n \t). What I mean is your response must look like this  [**\\\**\n].. Tested with gson library.

```
"some_string": "This is a string.\\\\r\\\\\nIt also has returns and newlines"
```